# How to write data to hive table with snappy compression in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark

I have an orc hive table that is created using Hive command

```
create table orc1(line string) stored as orcfile
```

I want to write some data to this table using spark sql, I use following code  and want the data to be snappy compressed on HDFS

```
  test("test spark orc file format with compression") {
    import SESSION.implicits._
    Seq("Hello Spark", "Hello Hadoop").toDF("a").createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
    SESSION.sql("set hive.exec.compress.output=true")
    SESSION.sql("set mapred.output.compress=true")
    SESSION.sql("set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec")
    SESSION.sql("set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec")
    SESSION.sql("set mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK")
    SESSION.sql("insert overwrite table orc1 select a from tmp  ")
  }
```

The data is written, but it is `NOT` compressed with snnapy.

If I run the `insert overwrite` in Hive Beeline/Hive to write the data and use the above `set command` , then I could see that the table's files are compressed with snappy.

So, I would ask how to write data with snappy compression in Spark SQL 2.1 to orc tables  that are created by Hive

Comment: Were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the compression to snappy on the create table command like so

```
create table orc1(line string) stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Then any inserts to the table will be snappy compressed (I corrected `orcfile` to `orc` in the command also).

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it looks it doesn't work. I use `hdfs dfs -cat` to cat the content of the table's files, I am able to see `Hello and Hadoop` in it, so it should not be compressed. If it has been compressed, I should not be able to see the contents.